# Is it a security or performance issue to automatically add controllers to Router (removing need for routing)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance, rest, express

So I have written code to handle this, essentially it looks for any placeholder.controller.ts file in my project and uses the exported array of controllers to add routing. Controllers have to be default exported in an array with a specific format.

the format looks like this:

```js
const controller1 = {
    endpoint: '/hello/world',
    method: 'get',
    controller: () => console.log('hello world!'),
  }

export default [
  controller1
];
```

The routing code that handles all of this, exists in a routes.ts file and looks like this:

```js
import glob from 'glob';
import path from 'path';
import { Router } from 'express';
import { toArray } from '../lib/utilities/generic-utilities';
import { isRouteType, isArrayWithContent } from '../lib/utilities/type-checking';
import { skip } from '../lib/middleware/generic-middleware';
import { Route } from '../meta/@types/common-types';
import { secureRoutesConstant, extension } from './settings';
import secureRoute from '../lib/middleware/secure-route';

const router: any = Router({ mergeParams: true });

// relative path from routes file to controllers folder.
const controllersPath = '../http/controllers/';

const addRouteToRouter = (route: Route, filename: string) => {
  const acceptableRoute: object | boolean = isRouteType(route);
  const message: string = `issue with route while exporting a controller in file ${filename}\nroute supplied was:`;

  if (!acceptableRoute) console.log(message, route);
  if (!acceptableRoute) return;

  const { endpoint, controller, method, isSecure = secureRoutesConstant } = route;
  const { middlewareBefore = [], middlewareAfter = [] } = route;

  const makeRouteSecure: Function = isSecure ? secureRoute : skip;
  const middlewareBeforeArr: Function[] = toArray(middlewareBefore);
  const middlewareAfterArr: Function[] = toArray(middlewareAfter);

  const routeArguments: Function[] = [
    ...middlewareBeforeArr,
    makeRouteSecure,
    controller,
    ...middlewareAfterArr,
  ];

  router.route(endpoint)[method](...routeArguments);
};

const addToRouterForEach = (allRoutes: Route[], filename: string) =>
  allRoutes.forEach((route: Route) => addRouteToRouter(route, filename));

glob
  .sync('**/*.ts', { cwd: path.join(`${__dirname}/`, controllersPath) })
  .filter((filename: string) => filename.split('.').includes('controller'))
  .map((filename: string) => ({ defaultsObj: require(`${controllersPath}${filename}`), filename }))
  .filter(({ defaultsObj }) => isArrayWithContent(defaultsObj.default))
  .forEach(({ defaultsObj, filename }) => addToRouterForEach(defaultsObj.default, filename));

export default router;
```

And is simply imported into app.ts and used like this:

```js
app.use('/api', router)
```

Essentially this means I have no routing code as it's all handled for me, I only have to write my services, controllers and models.

Is there any performance or security issues with doing things like this, or with the code itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any performance or security issues with doing things like this, or with the code itself?

## Performance

No. The auto code will only run on boot and even if it takes a second its not a cost you are paying on individual client request route handling.

## Security

The code architecture is secure by itself and does not increase your risk of vulnerabilites.